# Facebook Send dialog gives 100 error when sending Facebook urls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook send dialog to send links to Facebook posts. But I get the following error back from the Facebook API:

> ```
> API Error Code: 100
> API Error Description: Invalid parameter
> Error Message: 'link' is invalid.
> ```

This is the JavaScript:

```
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
  <script>
    // assume we are already logged in
    FB.init({appId: '569858063028330'});

    FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
      link: 'https://www.facebook.com/benjerryuk/posts/10151500944440101'
    });
  </script>
```

You can run it here:
http://jsbin.com/welcome/62834/edit

Facebook send dialog documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find it written specifically, but from my attempts it seems that facebook does not accept links to itself for some reason - I can't confirm this, but I got the same result even when I put links of public posts or profiles.

You might have the link refer to your app, which will redirect to the correct facebook post.

Another note: while showing this dialog, facebook loads the given link with AJAX, which means that A) it must be an active URL and B) you cannot use localhost.

Hope that helps.